# Can I stream HTTP data out of order?

Tags: http, streaming

OK, I know this is a long shot:

Does HTTP offer a way to stream a file out of order?  I'm dealing with a binary file format which can *almost* be streamed, except the header requires some summary data, and it would be a much better user experience if I could stream it.

It seems like it would be really great to be able to send the last part of a file first, then the header, like BitTorrent &co, but it also seems obscure enough that I'm not optimistic.

Thanks!

Comment: Just responding to your comment below (not sure if you'd get a notification if I responded to mine) - you could always post process those files to arrange the data how you want.  And if they're some kind of file that's not standard then you might have to write some client side code to handle the download anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a HEAD request to get the content length and then do range requests - I don't think you can just stream out of order though.  You may be able to get away without using a HEAD request as well.  Take a look [at Content-range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

Comment: That's a good idea, and I think it would work if I controlled both the server and the client.  But in this case I want to do out-of-order streaming to ordinary web browsers, and it doesn't look like there's a way for a server to say "please ask for the end first, since I can deliver that more quickly", and there's no way for a client to guess that that's the case.  Oh well.